# Docker can't run image on a server

Tags: docker, server

I am using docker on a distance server and I have a problem. When I use `docker run myimage` I have this error :

```
docker: Error response from daemon: all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock: timeout": unavailable.
```

I try to run my image on an other server and it worked well. I tried to run other images on this server and I had the same error.

Where does this error come from ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this server you're trying to reach simply not responding maybe is down or network issues or something is wrong with the docker setup inside the server.